# Detect corrupt xlsx file (zip zith changed extension) pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a small xlsx file checker, I need to implement a file corruption check. I have the following code

```
try:
    check_file = pandas.ExcelFile(input_excel)
except IOError: sys.exit("Unsupported format, or corrupt file")
```

It throws an exception for all kind of files with changed extension, except of archives. So my question is, how can I detect archives with extension changed to an xlsx and throw an exception on them.
I am working with Python 3.6, pandas and numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was in the exception type, I have changed it to the more general Exception type of exception, and now it works.